# Output data from table A based on result from table B for only 3 number at the back without space and alphabet

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to output data from table A based on query from table B. But the table A result that outputs should be only 3 numbers at the end of result obtain from subquery of table B. I use like operator but if it is number and alphabet at the back or space between two number it also outputs. How can i solve this issue

```
    select  tA.userName      
    from tableA tA
    where  tA.userName like 
    (select tB.name from tableB tB where tB.ID = 'E044')
    || '%';
```

My data in TABLE B data is

```
    ID          NAME
    ------      ------
    E044        ADAM
    E045        JOE
```

My data in TABLE A data is

```
    USERNAME
    ------------
    ADAM
    ADAM1
    ADAM22
    ADAM6
    ADAM333
    ADAM5 5
    JOE6
    ADAM4444
    ADAM 5
    ADAM4MAKE
    ADAM 4 MAKER
```

Output should be whereby it should take ADAM and only 3 digit numbers without space in between the number and character

```
    USERNAME
    ------------
    ADAM   
    ADAM1
    ADAM22
    ADAM6
    ADAM333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_like()`, but you need to be careful about the pattern:

```
select  tA.userName      
from tableA tA join
     tableB tB 
     on regexp_like(tA.userName, '^' || tB.name || '[0-9]{0,3}$')
WHERE tB.ID = 'E044';
```

Comment: What about exactly 'ADAM'?

Comment: can i know what the purpose of $

Comment: @jake match the end of the string

Comment: Shouldn't It be ´{0,3}´ instead of ´{3}´?

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound . . . Yes.  I was focusing more on the description ("ADAM and only 3 digit numbers") than on the sample results.

Comment: it gives syntax error before the where and after the ...0-9]{0,3}$').. but when i run no error... but there is a pink line stating syntax error expected (paren_expr_list) when i move my mouse over the pink line

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm)

Your match criteria for three numbers will be `[0-9]{0,3}`:

```
select  tA.userName      
from tableA tA 
INNER JOIN tableB tB 
ON REGEXP_LIKE (tA.userName, tB.name || '[0-9]{0,3}')
WHERE tB.ID = 'E044'
```